# Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found

Tags: joomla

I am recently start work in Joomla and I have an error please help me

> Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in   joomla/helpers/system.php
>   on line 48 the line show in 48 row is

```
$this->application = JFactory::getApplication();
```

Comment: You really need to provide us with more information.

Comment: have you modified any code ??

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ensure you have the latest version of the build you're using. So either 1.5.26, 2.5.8, or 3.0.2

Once done, download a fresh copy of Joomla, extract the **"includes"** and **"libraries"** folders, and upload these 2 folder (preferably as zip files) via the FTP and extract them.

As a little side note. If you already have, please don't edit any core Joomla files. This can cause all sorts of problems on the security and functionality side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and I later discovered that factory.php file was missing from "libraries/joomla" directory. I'm not sure how that happened but I replaced the file from an update zip file and that solved it.